# How to Check for Image in Cache Using Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, caching

I am creating a basic image browsing application using Silverlight.  Depending on the user's connection speed, some images may take time to appear once they click on the thumb nail.  I would like to show a progress bar while it is being downloaded.  I have this part done.

However, if the image is already in the cache (viewing a previous image), I'd rather not have the progress bar flash up and then disappear.  Is there a way to see if a particular file is in the cache before I display my progress bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking about it for a while, I did come up with one solution, though it wasn't what I was originally intending.

I am using the WebClient class to get my image file.  I attach to the DownloadProgressChanged event.  If the image has already been downloaded, then the ProgressPercentage is immediately 100.

So instead of making the ProgressBar visibile when I call OpenReadAsync and making it invisible when the Completed event is fired, I set the visibility in the DownloadProgressChanged event handler.